# Using angular from both atmosphere and npm gives warning

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-leaflet-directive

Using `Meteor 1.3.2.4` I do:

```
meteor create myapp
cd myapp
meteor npm install --save angular
meteor add angularjs:angular
```

and in `main.js` add as first line

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

This gives me

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

in the browser console.

I guess this is because angular packages from both `npm` and `atmosphere` are added, but I do not know how to circumvent this if I need an `atmosphere` package that depends on `angularjs:angular` and also want to to use `angular` from `npm` (for example when using `angular-meteor`). More specifically I want to use the package [angular-leaflet-directive](https://atmospherejs.com/piotrkaczmarek/angular-leaflet-directive) in a `meteor/angular` app. Any suggestions ?
I asked the same question [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/conflict-when-using-angular-from-npm-and-atmosphere/22959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package author needs to follow those [instructions here](http://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html#angular-meteor-packages) to make his package work on both Meteor 1.3 and Meteor 1.2 and earlier.

Maybe you could submit a pull request for him and until he will merge it, you could publish to Atmosphere under your own user.

Also, you could just bring `angular-leaflet-directive` from npm!

Comment: I use angular-leaflet-directive from npm now. I could not find a public repository of the atmosphere package.